# Replace Zombie Spawner w/ Default Vanilla Skeleton Spawner

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Nearest skeleton spawner is 4000 blocks away. I wanna replace one zombie spawner with a regular vanilla skeleton spawner. Anyone know the game code to spawn these buddies with randomized armor and bows the way they are in standard vanilla? I used a `/setblock` code but it doesn't seem to spawn skeletons with random items.

Answer (score 1):

In legitimate Vanilla Survival, it's impossible to move, make, or replace mob spawners, they're 100% fixed to their initial position.

However in Creative mode, you can replace what mobs the mob spawner spawns in by using a spawn egg on it.

A notable thing to mention is that depending on your game version (Bedrock or Java) you can get the actual spawner block in different ways in Creative mode, on Bedrock Edition you can find the empty mob spawner block in the Creative inventory itself, however on Java Edition you'd need to use the `/give` or `/setblock` command to obtain empty mob spawners.

To activate the empty mob spawner, you use any spawn egg on it to turn it into a mob spawner of that specific mob.